# UICollectionViewCell subclass init never run

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have added a collection view in viewDidLoad like this...

```
self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CameraCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CameraCellReuseIdentifier];
[self.collectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];
```

And I have a UICollectionViewCell subclass called CameraCell with an init like this...

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Add customisation here...
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(imageChanged:) name:@"image" object:nil];

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [self.imageView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];

        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_imageView);

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_imageView]|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:views]];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[_imageView]|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:views]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

But when I run the app the collection view is there and I can scroll it but I can't see any cells. I have added a breakpoint in the cell's init and it never gets called. Is there another method I have to override?

**EDIT**

When I log the cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath...

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CameraCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CameraCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"%@", cell);

    return cell;
}
```

It displays the correct class...

```
<CameraCell: 0x1f07ba30; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 20; 320 280); layer = <CALayer: 0x1f07bb40>>
```

Comment: I mean, you are calling initWithFrame instead of init...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The method you need to implement is `- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect`

Comment: OMG I can't believe I did that. Thanks.

Comment: But isn't the frame governed by `collectionView` itself—rendering this `initWithFrame` from the `collectionViewCell` useless?

Comment: The frame argument you get is kind of useless, but you will still need to initialize your own properties here.

Answer (score 28):

I recently tried this in the iOS7 SDK, and I had to override `initWithCoder` because `initWithFrame` was never called.

Comment: Were you loading it from a storyboard or nib? Or all in code?

Comment: The cell is loaded from a Storyboard.

Comment: ^Then that's why. `initWithCoder` is the designated initializer for views built from the storyboard. `initWithFrame` is for views that are built programatically.

Comment: Frequent problem :) I usually put all construction in `init`, and then call it from overridden `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder`. it makes cell class more universal.
Or, when I need to save original initWithCoder behavior, I make another one method `universalInit`, put all my custom code there and call it from all default initializers.
Of course, with Swift this trick is no more handy.

Answer (score 24):

If the cell is loaded from a StoryBoard then you will want to override the initializers like this:

**Swift**

```
override init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder:aDecoder)
  //You Code here
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
  //You code here
}
```

If you are loading from a nib, then you will want to override the initializers like this:

**Swift**

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
  super.init(frame:frame)
  //You Code here
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
  self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
  //You code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is way old, but personally I was lazy and wanted to copy-paste code from somewhere. Unfortunately, there is no 100% correct solution above so I wrote common pattern (for both IB-based and code-based cells)

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        commonInit()
    }
    
    private func commonInit() {
        
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, when I am using `[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10) collectionViewLayout:flowLayout]` to programatically instantiate a collectionView, `initWithFrame` never get called, but `initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame collectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout` did.

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 5:**

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    // Your code here.
}
```

Comment: Any reason for why you downvoted my question?